# identifying if word in already in binary search tree (recursion) working extremely slow/inaccurately

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am not sure what is wrong with my containsKey() method in the following code. It is supposed to return true if the word is in the map and false if it is not. I have a BSTMap class and an inner TreeNode class (every word being a TreeNode key, and the number of times the word appears being the TreeNode value).  Please help!! I think it has to do with the recursion in line 183, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. The comparator is supposed to speed up the amount of time it takes to find the word, because it is not traversing the whole tree.

```
/**
 * Jesse Aphridion
 * 04/04/2017
 * BSTMap.java
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BSTMap<Key,Value> implements MyMap<Key,Value> {

    private TreeNode<Key,Value> root;
    private Comparator<Key> comparator;
    private int size;
    private int depth;

    public BSTMap( Comparator<Key> comparator ) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.root = null;
        this.size = 0;
        this.depth = 0;
    }


    public boolean containsKey( Key k ){
        if ( this.root == null ){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return root.containsKey( k, this.comparator );
//          System.out.println( "if contain: " + root.ifContain );
//          return root.ifContain;
        }
    }





    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "test code" );
        BSTMap<String,Integer> map = new BSTMap<String,Integer>(new AscendingStringComparator());

}

class TreeNode<Key,Value> {

    private KeyValuePair<Key,Value> pair;
    private TreeNode<Key,Value> left;
    private TreeNode<Key,Value> right;
    public boolean ifContain;

    public TreeNode( Key this_key, Value this_val, TreeNode<Key,Value> l, TreeNode<Key,Value> r ) {
        ; // code here
        this.pair = new KeyValuePair<Key, Value>(this_key, this_val);
        this.left = l;
        this.right = r;
        this.ifContain = false;
    }

public Key getKey(){
    return this.pair.getKey();
}

    public boolean containsKey( Key k, Comparator<Key> comparator ){ ////USE COMPARATORRRRRRR
        this.ifContain = false;
        int compRslt = comparator.compare(k, pair.getKey());
        System.out.println( k );
        if ( compRslt == 0 ){
            System.out.println("comparator 0, set true");
            this.ifContain = true;
            return this.ifContain;
        }

        else if ( compRslt < 0 ){
            if (left == null) {
                System.out.println("comparator < 0, set false");
                this.ifContain = false;
                return this.ifContain;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("call left contains key");
                return this.left.containsKey( k, comparator );
            }
        }
        else{
            if (right == null) {
                System.out.println("right is null, set false");
                this.ifContain = false;
                return this.ifContain;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("call right contains key");
                return this.right.containsKey( k, comparator );
            }
        }
        //System.out.println( this.ifContain );
        //return this.ifContain;
    }

}

class AscendingStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare( String i1, String i2 ) {
        // returns negative number if i2 comes after i1 lexicographically
        //0 if same
        // pos number if i2 comes before i1
        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
}
```

Comment: far too much code to read. try and reduce the code to the problem.

Comment: reduced to relevant code!